# How to restart css transitions with "touchstart" and "touchend"?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple div that simulates the ripple effect of material design along with "touchstart" and "touchend" events. But I don't know how to restart the animation if the user clicks several times.

```
      .test-ripple{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
   
  }
     .test-ripple:before {
        display: none;
      }
      .test-ripple:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        cursor: pointer;
        background-image: none;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        width: 78%;
        height: 78%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        transform: scale(0.3);
        transition: linear 350ms forwards;
      }

      .test-ripple.ativo:after {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        transform: scale(1);
        transition: 150ms;
      }
      .test-ripple.fade-out:after {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        transition: 300ms;
      }

 
<div class="test-ripple">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</div >

var ripple = document.querySelectorAll(".test-ripple")

        ripple.forEach((item) => {
          item.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
            item.classList.add("ativo");

          });

          item.addEventListener("touchend", () => {
            setTimeout(function () {
              item.classList.add("fade-out");
              setTimeout(function () {
                item.classList.remove("ativo");
                item.classList.remove("fade-out");
              }, 150);
            }, 100);
          });
        });
```

How to make the transition repeat each time the user clicks?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm with what I have seen so far there is no special code for that, just write your code add only one call function forthe animation to start so when the user click's again it definitely will restart automatically